# Meaning of "smart crack"

Tags: meaning

> Elizabeth did not want to tell Dexter about her mother. Although the news
> was more than a year old, he would be so portentously and profoundly sorry
> for her that **she would be embarrassed into making some smart crack**, which
> would shock and grieve him and then he would rebuke her and she would
> not be able to prevent herself from blushing and hanging her head. She
> wanted to say, as well, ‘Don’t call me Morty. Nobody calls me that any
> more.’ But that would sound snotty and he would laugh at her.
>
> ‘Mum died,’ she said. ‘And don’t you dare feel sorry for me.’

Does "smart crack" mean "wisecrack"?

Does the sentence "she would be embarrassed into making some smart crack" mean: because she would not want to be more embarrassed and awkward she would say somethings that would be funny and comical?

Does "making smart crack" mean "saying somethings ironically to someone"?

Source: The Children's Bach by Helen Garner.

Comment: Yes, it's as define by [Collins dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crack) - **crack** noun (JOKE) - *a wisecrack, **informal**.* Presumably the usage arose via ***to crack a joke*** (after which there might be an "explosion" of laughter, drawing on the same imagery as ***cracking open a can of Coke*** - the froth / bubbles of which might then spew forth).

Comment: She would feel embarrassed at Dexter's sympathy and as a result she would (or  feared that she would) make an inappropriate joke or remark intended to be witty.

Comment: can we say  "she would make smart crack" mean: she would say something ironically about him to mock him?

Comment: It's 'make **a** smart crack'. I don't think the meaning is that she would make a joke about Dexter, just that she would make an inappropriately humorous remark about the situation.